# .load() works with window, not with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

i want to execute a Command after finish loading a Div. Should be easy, but i couldn´t handle it.

```js
//With window it works fine
$(window).load(function()
{
 alert($("#firstAmazon").attr("class"));
});

//With an other Object not
$("#firstAmazon").load(function()
{
 alert("firstAmazon loaded");

});
```

```html
<div class="socialIcon" id="firstAmazon">
 <a href="amazon" title="Amazon">
 <img src="../img/socialBar/amazon.png">
 </a>
</div>
```

That comment was very helpful

> div elements do not raise a load event, only the document, window and
>   img elements do. – Rory McCrossan 16 mins ago

Actually i want to execute teh command after loading the img (amazon.png), So document ready don´t help me.

it works not like the documentation. I want that the load() fires after the Image is loaded.

```js
$("#firstPic").load(function()
{
 alert("firstPic loaded");

});
```

```html
<div class="socialIcon">
 <img  id="firstPic" src="http://www.smartturtle.com/img/header.jpg">
</div>
```

here the documentation http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

```js
$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

```html
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book">
```

Comment: `div` elements do not raise a `load` event, only the `document`, `window` and `img` elements do.

Comment: use Document.ready event of jquery. ready event fire only when div get render.

Answer (score 0):

The `div` elements do not raise a load event.

Use `document.ready` handler as shown :-

```
$(function(){
   alert("firstAmazon loaded");
});
```

The `document.ready` handler executes after the DOM is completely loaded.

Comment: Actually i want to execute the command after loading the img (amazon.png), So document ready don´t help me.

Comment: @DavidSiebenförcher...you can use `.load()` for images .. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Answer (score 0):

Use this [document ready function()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("firstAmazon loaded");
});
```

Comment: Actually i want to execute the command after loading the img (amazon.png), So document ready don´t help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way to check div loaded

```
var interval;
window.onload = createInterval(); 

function createInterval(){ 
   interval=setInterval(readyCheck(),100); 
} 

function readyCheck(){ 
  if($('#firstAmazon img').get(0).complete){ 
     clearInterval(interval); 
     alert('firstAmazon loaded'); 
  } 
  else { 
     alert('firstAmazon loading');
  } 
}
```

Comment: it starts the interval, but never fires any alert

Comment: may be jQuery version conflict, try this line interval=setInterval(readyCheck(),100); instead of interval=setInterval("readyCheck()",100);

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                    $(window).load(function(){
                      alert($("#firstAmazon").attr("class"));
                    });

                });
            </script>
```

Comment: the window.load function sill works, but i get never a flag when a image is loaded.

Comment: Actually i want to execute the command after loading the img (amazon.png), So that doesn´t helps me.